# What are the characters in this seal? (Characters identified: 白云長滿目)

Tags: character-identification, seal

Does this phrase comes from a poetic or philosophical text?

[image]

---

Many thanks for your translation and your comments on this deal.
Actually I had not too much problems with the 云 yún character because I have 2 others seals with this kind of symbolic script.
My problem was with the 滿 mǎn character I was unable to recognize.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characters are 白云長滿目, which roughly translates to

> *The vast expanse of white clouds, filling one's sight,*

coming from the poem 《送廬山人歸林慮山》 by the [Táng Dynasty poet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tang_poetry#Middle_Tang) [Huángfǔ Rǎn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huangfu_Ran).

「云」 is particularly difficult to identify, and is worthy of some additional explanation.

---

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image: 云]
[乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)12
[合集21021](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21021&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
甲
[image: 云]
[前](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)6.43.4
[合集17072](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=17072&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 云]
姑發劍
[集成11718](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=11718)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 云]
[緇衣](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/ChuwenziReference)・35
[郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips)</kbd>
<kbd>[說文古文](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%8F%A4%E6%96%87_(%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97))
[image: 云]
[雲部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=131)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image: 云]</kbd>

「云」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[ɢ]ʷə[r]/**, *clouds*) is comprised of semantic [「」 (*up/above*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=24), now written 「上」) and phonetic

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
[京津](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)4726
[合集21324](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21324&jgwfl=)</kbd>

(**/*[ɢ](r)ə[r]ʔ/**). This character is [「旬」 before the addition of a 「日」 component](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=392).

Occasionally, the 「」 part of 「云」 may be partially or fully omitted, and the remainder may be rotated or distorted in some way. This forms the inspiration behind

<kbd>說文古文
[image]
雲部
說文解字</kbd>

which is the shape in the seal.

---

**References**:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)
- [宋・徐鉉等奉敕校定　漢・許慎《說文解字》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&res=77351)